# How to have a UIButton image change when a button is touched

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uicontrol

I'm trying to have the UIButton image change when a button is touched. Currently I it changes but only on the highlighted state change. I would like it to change and stay there. I tried UIControlStateSelected for the state change but no luck.

thanks for the help

here's my code:

```
 // Create buttons for the sliding category menu.
    NSMutableArray* buttonArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray * myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"category-cafe-unsel.png", @"category-food-unsel.png", @"category-clothing-unsel.png", @"category-health-unsel.png", @"category-tech-unsel_phone.png" , @"category-tech2-unsel.png", @"catefory-theatre-unsel.png", @"category-travel-unsel.png", nil];

    NSArray * myImagesSel = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"category-cafe-sel.png", @"category-food-sel.png", @"category-clothing-sel.png", @"category-health-sel.png", @"category-tech-sel_phone.png" , @"category-tech2-sel.png", @"catefory-theatre-sel.png", @"category-travel-sel.png", nil];

    // only create the amount of buttons based on the image array count
    for(int i = 0;i < [myImages count]; i++)
    {
        // Custom UIButton

        btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 52.0f, 52.0f)];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImagesSel objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        NSLog(@"The button title is %@ ", btn.titleLabel.text);

        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [buttonArray addObject:btn];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your IBAction method add the following lines:

```
 - (IBAction)change:(id)sender
 {
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   int tagOfButton = button.tag - 1;
   [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImagesSel objectAtIndex:tagOfButton]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

Add a single line to your for loop like:

```
for(int i = 0;i < [myImages count]; i++)
{
    // other stuffs
    btn.tag  = i+1;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to undone the previous selection when other button is clicked:

write this loop inside your IBAction method.

```
for(int i = 0;i < [myImages count]; i++)
{
  UIButton *but = (UIButton *)[buttonArray objectAtIndex:i];
  if(but != button)
  {
       [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
}
```

Or simply store the previous button tag to a variable.
And use it to change undone the image change.

Comment: thanks. it's switching around the images - so the wrong image displays. They appear to be one off, where instead of the first item in the image array displays the second one displays instead. Also the state is not undone when another button is touched. thanks for your help :)

Comment: I changed the code to int tagOfButton = button.tag - 2; and the correct image is now showing. I just them to return to default when another button is touched. :)

Comment: @hanumanDev: did you write the above code inside your IBAction method ? Is the loop working ?

Answer (score 0):

```
[btn setTitle:@"I'm not selected" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitle:@"I'm selected" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImagesSel objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
  btn.selected = !btn.selected;
}
```